# HTTP/1.0 request blocked on read() (C program)

Tags: http, get, httprequest

I'm building a simple program that connects to a google server and sends a GET request with HTTP/1.0.
This is the line I'm sending:

```
char get[] = "GET /?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=0PfNWpaWJ8vA8gfnuK-wDw HTTP/1.0\r\n";
write(s,get,strlen(get));
```

And then I iterate the read while it has more bytes to read.

```
    char buffer[10000];
    int pos=0;
    while((t = read(s,buffer+pos,1))!=0){
            pos++;
    }
    printf("END");
```

The printf is never reached.
Instead, if I send this line the program works correctly
(this is a simple-request, while the one before was a full-request)

```
char get[] = "GET /?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=0PfNWpaWJ8vA8gfnuK-wDw\r\n";
write(s,get,strlen(get));
```

Why does the program blocks on the read? I mean, if it was a problem of request it should return a 400 error. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. A full-request, is composed as stated in the RFC1945:

> Full-Request   = Request-Line
>                           *( General-Header
>                            | Request-Header
>                            | Entity-Header )
>                           CRLF
>                           [ Entity-Body ]

And a Request line is

> Request-Line = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

Therefore, in my case, the GET must end with a double CLRF.
Thanks to @CodeCaster

Answer (score 2):

A full-request ends with a double CRLF. You only send one, so the server is waiting for the rest of the request.